# Output SQL as string from pandas.DataFrame.to_sql

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

Is there a way of making pandas (or sqlalchemy) output the SQL that would be executed by a call to `to_sql()` instead of actually executing it? This would be handy in many cases where I actually need to update multiple databases with the same data where python and pandas only exists in one of my machines.

Comment: Can you give example?

Comment: It is quite a generic question. Say we have a dataframe A composed of data from a database and we do some calculation changing some column set C. We then want to update several database servers with the new information. Instead of needing a full python installation along with pandas and all relevant libraries installed in each machine it would be nice to be able to do something like A.gen_sql(...) and generate an sql (text) output of the insert / update statements that would update each server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more a process question than a programming one. First, is the use of multiple databases. Relational databases management systems (RDMBS) are designed as multiple-user systems for many simultaneous users/apps/clients/machines. Designed to run as ONE system, the database serves as the central repository for related applications. Some argue databases should be agnostic to apps and be data-centric (Postgre folks) and others believe databases should be app-centric (MySQL folks). Overall, understand they are more involved than a flatfile spreadsheet or data frame.

Usually, RDMS's come in two structural types:

1. **file level systems** like SQLite and MS Access (where databases reside in a file saved to CPU directory); these systems though still powerful and multi-user mostly serve for smaller business applications with relatively handful of users or team sizes
2. **server-level systems** like SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, DB2, Oracle (where databases run over a network without any localized file); these systems serve as enterprise level systems to run full-scale business operations run over LAN intranets or web networks.

Meanwhile, Pandas is not a database but a data analysis toolkit (much like MS Excel) though it can import/export queried resultsets from RDMS's. Therefore, it maintains no native SQL dialect for [DDL/DML](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=ddldml.php) procedures. Moreover, pandas runs in memory on the OS calling the Python script and cannot be shared by other clients/machines. Pandas does not track changes like you intend in order to know the different states of a data frame during runtime of script unless you design it that way with a before and after and identify column/row changes.

With that mouthful said, why not use ONE database and have your Python script serve as just another of the many clients that connect to the database to import/export data into data frame. Hence, after every data frame change actually run the `to_sql()`. Recall pandas' [to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) uses the `if_exists` argument:

```
# DROPS TABLE, RECREATES IT, AND UPDATES IT
df.to_sql(name='tablename', con=conn, if_exists='replace')

# APPENDS DF DATA TO EXISTING TABLE
df.to_sql(name='tablename', con=conn, if_exists='append')
```

In turn, every app/machine that connects to the centralized database will only need to refresh their instance and current data would be available in real-time for their end use needs. Though of course, table-locking states can be an issue in multi-user environments if another user had a table record in edit mode while your script tried updating it. But transactions here may help.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Your "why not" suggestion is sort of what I am currently doing.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html?highlight=echo#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.echo), use the echo parameter as:

`engine = create_engine("mysql://scott:tiger@hostname/dbname", echo=True)`