# How to generate SQL using pandas without a database connection?

Tags: python, pandas

The `pandas` package have a method called `.to_sql` that help to insert the current data frame on to the database.

`.to_sql` doc:

> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

The second parameter is `con`

> sqlalchemy.engine.(Engine or Connection) or sqlite3.Connection

Is it possible to generate the SQL query without passing a database connection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output SQL as string from pandas.DataFrame.to\_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920127/output-sql-as-string-from-pandas-dataframe-to-sql)

Comment: @Laurent actually no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually cannot print the query without a database connection, but we can use `sqlalchemy` [`create_mock_engine`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_mock_engine) method and pass "memory" as the database URI to trick `pandas`, e.g:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_mock_engine, Metadata

def dump(sql, *multiparams, **params):
    print(sql.compile(dialect=engine.dialect))

engine = create_mock_engine("sqlite://:memory:", echo=True)
Metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=False)

frame.to_sql(engine)
```